# Save All Attributes of Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, save

I have a user model that has many carts

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carts
```

If I update a cart:

```
User.last.carts.last.time_purchased = Time.now
```

Is there a way I can save the whole user model?  Now, if I call

```
User.last.save
```

The cart that I modified is not saved.

```
User.last.carts.last.save
```

Does save the cart.

Is there a way to save all updated attributes of a model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving a model *will* save any of its associations, but the reason this isn't working for you is because you are re-fetching the `User` model instead of modifying and saving the same instance.

```
user = User.last
user.carts.last.time_purchased = Time.now
user.save
```

Saving the user should also save the associated cart.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are fetching a copy of the cart, modifying it, then fetching another copy of the cart and saving *that*.

You should save the cart in a variable, then apply the save on that. For example:

```
cart = User.last.carts.last
cart.time_purchased = Time.now
cart.save
```

Alternatively, you can use update_attribute, like this:

```
User.last.carts.last.update_attribute(:time_purchased, Time.now)
```